# login with credentials fail with sfDoctrineGuard in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

So I've this application and have to grant access to type of people the admin and a little group of people who have to edit a little part of an module. 
Lets say I've a module which has fields [A, B, C, D], and a group of people need to change the default value of some os the items that module represents, for instance C and D.
Now I've created the the groups, setted the permissions and assigned the test user to that group, editted the security.yml like this: credentials: [[admin, certificatore]] as i need to be an or. Try to access it's not letting me in. where i'm going wrong? myUser extends the sfGuardSecurityUser.

I've noticed that in DB the user, group and permission I've created are not present, but from the backend i can see them...

Comment: First check why you see the user in the backend and not in the db. The problem might be there. Maybe you're checking different tables or you have some separate databases for your project (or environments). Also check in the dev toolbar as which user you are logged in and if you have the proper permissions listed there.

Comment: So they were in the other database.. Now how can i make it work?

Comment: Ok I've switched to the other db but still not working, it's redirecting me to home... pelase suggest something.

Comment: Did you logout and login again? (make sure the session has been reset) You should try to check where the redirection happens. I don't remember sfDoctrineGuard to make redirections other than during login/logout so you should check your own code.

Comment: Yes @MichalTrojanowski have tried login and logout, deleting cookie destroying sessions but still the problem persists. Will check for the redirections. other suggestions?

Comment: I still think it's a problem in the code itself. `sfDoctrineGuard` does not make any redirections when the user has insufficient credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting contents of cache folder?

Comment: yup, every time i make changes give this ./symfony cc